# C# Error (Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int')

Tags: c#

please help! I have not idea how to fix this.I am stuck on this and it has been a while. What should this code look like at lease the error is in line 8-10

```
        int intAmountA = 0;
        int intAmountB = 0;
        int intAmountC = 0;
        decimal decPackageA = 0m;
        decimal decPackageB = 0m;
        decimal decPackageC = 0m;
        decimal decTotal = 0m;

        intAmountA = TxtAmountA.Text;
        intAmountB = TxtAmountB.Text;
        intAmountC = TxtAmountC.Text;

        decPackageA = intAmountA * 150;
        decPackageB = intAmountB * 120;
        decPackageC = intAmountC * 90;

        LblPackageA.Text = decPackageA.ToString("c");
        LblPackageB.Text = decPackageB.ToString("c");
        LblPackageC.Text = decPackageC.ToString("c");

        decTotal = decPackageA + decPackageB + decPackageC;


        LblTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("c");
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `TxtAmountA.Text` is a string.  You are attempting to set the variable `intAmountA` which is an integer to a string value, thus the error.  You need to parse the integer out of the string in the textbox.

```
intAmountA = int.Parse(TxtAmountA.Text);
```

However, be aware that if what is in `TxtAmountA.Text` is not something that can be cast to an integer, you will get an exception.  That is when you can use the conditional `int.TryParse(string value, out integer);`

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to learn about:

- *[Casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)*
- *[Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)*

Both are basic task, but are incredibly important to programming.

You have a couple of approaches:

```
intAmount = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);
intAmount = int.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
```

The easiest approach to `cast` would be the above. However, the problem will occur when invalid user information may be passed.  For instance a user passes `example` would cause an Exception.

You'll want to sanitize the data.  So you could try the following:

```
int amount;
if(int.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out amount))
{
     // Properly converted amount to an integer.
}
```

Another approach could be:

```
int amount = txtAmount.Text.Where(d => char.IsDigit(d));
```

The safest and most common would be `int.TryParse`.  But these are all approaches you should look into to properly handle data.

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

```
intAmountA = TxtAmountA.Text;
intAmountB = TxtAmountB.Text;
intAmountC = TxtAmountC.Text;
```

You are assigning string type values to an int type variable.

This will convert the string values into their int type representations.
e.g. "1" => 1

```
intAmountA = int.Parse(TxtAmountA.Text);
intAmountB = int.Parse(TxtAmountB.Text);
intAmountC = int.Parse(TxtAmountC.Text);
```